# how to send mails to multiple list of emails from a database using php

Tags: php, email

i am working on script to send a mail to a list of emails from my table using php

presently i run a query on the table and echo all the emails meeting such requirements from the sql query

```
sql="SELECT * FROM people WHERE status in('member','client')"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die("Cannot query orders_products data" . mysql_error()); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $list = array();
$list[] = $row['Email']; 

echo implode(",",$list);

$email = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'; 
$emailto = implode( "," ,$list ); 

$subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 

$headers = "From: $email";

$body .= ++$i.") ".$row['title'] ."\n\n"; 
} 
$body .= "Regards\n\n"; 

$body .= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n\n";

$send = mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

when i try passing these emails to a mail function snippet the mail sending fails.

Please what could i be doin wrong, i need help

Update :

```
$list[] = $row['Email']; 

    echo implode(",",$list);
```

all the emails are displayed

But without commas.

```
$emailto = implode( "," ,$list );
```

i use the same method of imploding the array of data gotten from

`$list[] = $row['Email'];`

By fail i just mean i was hoping since the emails got echoed using the implode it would all successfully pass the emails to $emailto and then send a mail to each of them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow :) It's good that you included your code. Could you please clarify: "when i try passing these emails to a mail function snippet the mail sending fails." Is this function the last line of the code you provided? Could you please provide the stack trace, error message, or a description of what "fails" means?

Comment: Your database needs to be properly normalized

Comment: hi @MyStackRunnethOver i have updated my question to explain what fail means

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi how does your comment fit into the question being asked?

Comment: @chapman this `sql="SELECT * FROM people WHERE status in('member','client')";` shows that your table is not properly normalized. `status` could be on its own table, then you link it using id. This would help in having a totally separate table containing statuses as well as users linked. Read up on normalization here https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization . It'll save you future problems. From your above code, you need a proper PHP tutorial before jumping head first into writing any application

Comment: @chapman  Why all the insult? Carefully read my comment before responding anyhow. I added that comment because i fell victim to something similar and thought you could benefit from the tutorial. Normalization helps avoid issues in the future. trust me you need to always think of the future while writing code. Tutorials don't imply that you don't know anything. Its just there to keep you in check. Till this very day, i still google even the simplest thing. Just calm down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I think you're trying to do is to get the email address from your table where the user is either a member or a client.  Then, you have a from address, subject, and a body. In addition, it looks like maybe you're trying to add to the body some unique information.  Finally, I think you want to send an individual email to each user, separately.

You could modify your code to be like this:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM people WHERE status in('member','client')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot query orders_products data" . mysql_error());

$emailContent = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$emailSubject = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$body = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$headers = "From: from@email.com";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // optionally modify body here...?
  $emailBody = $body .= $row['title']; // or whatever you're trying to do here...

  // send email to each individual person
  mail($row['Email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody, $headers);
}
```

I *think* this is how you'd modify your code to get it to do what you're asking.